# Facebook Javascript: how to save a Facebook event

Tags: javascript, facebook

**Short version:**

On Facebook (Javascript SDK) I would like to "save" a Facebook event through Javascript, equivalent of clicking "Save" in the Facebook UI, but I can't find this in the SDK... any idea?

**Long version:**

To list a page's events, I do:

`FB.api('/somepage/events', function(response) { listEvents(response.data); });`

where:

```
function listEvents(listOfEvents)
{
  console.log("Number of Events: " + listOfEvents.length);
  for (i=0; i<listOfEvents.length; i++)
  {
    console.log("Event " + i + ": " + listOfEvents[i].name);
    // "save" that "listOfEvents[i]" event?
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no API for that.

Comment: @WizKid So is there a way with the API to add them to Facebook's calendar? The "subscribe to this page's events" functionality in the Facebook UI doesn't work for me, so I want to do this by hand with the API: be able to see in the calendar the available events from a bunch of pages...

Comment: _“The "subscribe to this page's events" functionality in the Facebook UI doesn't work for me”_ – you mean, the feature is broken? Then you should report it here, https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065

Comment: I already have, some people have the same problem, some not... no solution. I'm trying to find a do-it-yourself solution in Javascript -- can I just make events appear in my calendar without indicating publicly that I am going to all of them, which is not true? I just want them to appear in my calendar to be aware they exist (like the "save" feature of the UI does)...